# Nested If Statement in ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

is there any way to loop in the ForEach loop the following if statements? If I can't, what will be the best approach to shorten the code. The reason I am asking is xcode throws me error "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time". This type of coding is out of my league. Thank you in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    
    var lyrics: [Lyric] = LyricList.hymnLa
    @AppStorage("fontSizeIndex") var fontSizeIndex = Int("Medium") ?? 18
    @AppStorage("fontIndex") var fontIndex: String = ""
    @AppStorage("showHVNumbers") var showHVNumbers: Bool = true
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach (lyrics, id: \.id) { lyric in

                            if (lyric.verse2 != nil) {
                                HStack {
                                    if showHVNumbers {
                                        Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
                                            .font(.title2)
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    }

                                    Text(lyric.verse2 ?? "")
                                        .font(Font.custom(fontIndex, size: CGFloat(fontSizeIndex)))
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                            
                            
                            
                            if (lyric.verse3 != nil) {
                                HStack {
                                    if showHVNumbers {
                                        Image(systemName: "3.circle.fill")
                                            .font(.title2)
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    }
                                    
                                    Text(lyric.verse3 ?? "")
                                        .font(Font.custom(fontIndex, size: CGFloat(fontSizeIndex)))
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if (lyric.verse4 != nil) {
                                HStack {
                                    if showHVNumbers {
                                        Image(systemName: "4.circle.fill")
                                            .font(.title2)
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    }
                                    
                                    Text(lyric.verse4 ?? "")
                                        .font(Font.custom(fontIndex, size: CGFloat(fontSizeIndex)))
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if (lyric.verse5 != nil) {
                                HStack {
                                    if showHVNumbers {
                                        Image(systemName: "5.circle.fill")
                                            .font(.title2)
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    }
                                    
                                    Text(lyric.verse5 ?? "")
                                        .font(Font.custom(fontIndex, size: CGFloat(fontSizeIndex)))
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                        
                        Divider()
                    }
                    .onChange(of: scrollToIndex, perform: { value in
                        proxy.scrollTo(value, anchor: .top)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider to model the verses as an array. This is much more efficient than checking the existence of each verse. At the moment you are checking the verses 3-5 even if there are only 2 verses.

Comment: Just move ForEach internals into subviews

Comment: The reason I am checking verse by verse is some songs don't have verse 3, 4, or 5. Alternatively, some songs might have them.

Comment: What do you mean, moving ForEach into subviews? I am just a beginner level. Thanks for your answers Aperi and vadian.

Comment: One piece of the equation might be learning about “if let” and optional binding instead of doing the nil checks and then ?? coalescing later.

Comment: Is there any example or Youtube that I can learn?

Comment: you can find some info with example on "if let " from the Swift docs, at:    
    "https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html"
search for Optional Binding.

Comment: *some songs don't have verse 3, 4, or 5*. Yes, but you check verse 5 even if verse 3 is `nil` already.  If the verses are in an array and you enumerate this array, then all verses are being displayed regardless of the quantity.

Comment: @Asperi I know this but I forget and spent a full day. Thanks this works.