# Nesting ForEach loop and LazyVStack error

Tags: swiftui

I have encountered two issues below my codes. They should be a simple fix but I couldn't figure them out by myself.

The first issue is I cannot pass my nested ForEach loop to change the system images. The reason I used for nested ForEach loop is the Xcode always throw the error "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time". Here is the original link for this problem.
[Nested If Statement in ForEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082496/nested-if-statement-in-foreach-loop?noredirect=1#comment122097178_69082496)

```
import SwiftUI

struct HymnLyrics: View {
    
    let verseImages: [String] = ["2.circle.fill", "3.circle.fill", "4.circle.fill", "5.circle.fill"]
    
    var lyrics: [Lyric] = LyricList.hymnLa
    @AppStorage("fontSizeIndex") var fontSizeIndex = Int("Medium") ?? 18
    @AppStorage("fontIndex") var fontIndex: String = ""
    @AppStorage("showHVNumbers") var showHVNumbers: Bool = true
    @AppStorage("scrollToIndex") var scrollToIndex: Int?
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {//LazyVStack is crash
                    ForEach (lyrics, id: \.id) { lyric in
                        Group {
                            
                            HStack {
                                if showHVNumbers {
                                    Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                }
                                
                                Text(lyric.verse1)
                                    .font(Font.custom(fontIndex, size: CGFloat(fontSizeIndex)))
                                Spacer()
                            }

                            ForEach ([lyric.verse2, lyric.verse3, lyric.verse4, lyric.verse5], id: \.self) { verseCount in
                                if (verseCount != nil) {
                                    HStack {
                                        if showHVNumbers {
                                            Image(systemName: verseImages[verseCount])// Here is the error, it simply not works.
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                        }

                                        Text(verseCount ?? "")
                                            .font(Font.custom(fontIndex, size: CGFloat(fontSizeIndex)))
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                        
                        Divider()
                    }
                    .onChange(of: scrollToIndex, perform: { value in
                        proxy.scrollTo(value, anchor: .top)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second issue is the app crashed when I scroll down to the bottom. When I replace LazyVStack with regular VStact, it works. But I want to use LazyVStack in this case. Please guide me for both of the issues. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: What's `scrollToIndex`? Also try creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will make debugging much easier.

Comment: scrollToIndex is for ScrollViewReader. It will set the number that I want to read the page. We can ignore scrollToIndex for this case. The first issue is I cannot pass Image(systemName: verseImages[verseCount]) and the second issue is LazyVStack crash when I scroll to the bottom of the pages.

Comment: Try commenting out code until it works.