# Nested If statements inside ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui

I have created a custom list. Based on the conditions, some objects don't have names. Alternatively, some objects might have more than 1 name. So, the names in my custom list are optional. I want to print out all the names and I used the following codes. The code is working but it is too heavy. Sometimes, the Xcode throws "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in a reasonable time"

My DataArray Example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DataArray: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int
    let cities: String
    var name1: String?
    var name2: String?
    var name3: String?
    var name4: String?
}

public struct ListDataArray {
    static var dot = [
    DataArray(number: 1,
        cities: "Baltimore"
        name1: "A",
        name2: "B"),
        
    DataArray(number: 2,
        cities: "Frederick"),
        
    DataArray(number: 3,
        cities: "Catonsville"
        name1: "Aa",
        name2: "Bb",
        name3: "Cc",
        name4: "Dd"),
            
    ]
}


import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    
    var datas: [DataArray] = ListDataArray.dot

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach (datas, id: \.id) { data in
                    if (data.name1 !=nil) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)

                            Text(data.name1 ?? "")
                                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (data.name2 !=nil) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)

                            Text(data.name2 ?? "")
                                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (data.name3 !=nil) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "3.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)

                            Text(data.name3 ?? "")
                                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (data.name4 !=nil) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "4.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)

                            Text(data.name4 ?? "")
                                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, for the second approach, I used nested ForEach loop like

```
            ForEach (data, id: \.id) { data in
            
                ForEach ([data.name1, data.name2, data.name3, data.name4], id: .\self) { d in
                
                    if (d !=nil) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
                                            .font(.title2)
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)

                            Text(d ?? "")
                                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
```

The issue about this nested ForEach approach is that the LazyVStack always crashes when I scroll to the bottom of the pages. Also, I don't know how to update the system images. I can use regular VStack but these arrays will be a lot so I need LazyVStack. So, please help me to do a better way to shorten the if statements. Please please don't comment if you don't know or if you are not sure what you are doing. I posted similar questions four to five times here already. They all ended up with useless comments and they are worthless for a beginner level who really try to learn something new.

Comment: It's not clear what is included in `ListDataArray` or `DataArray`. Can you make a [mre] that can be copied and pasted into Xcode to be tested?

Comment: In your first, example, I'd change everything from `if (data.name1 != nil) ... data.name1 ?? ""` to `if let name1 = data.name1 ... name1`. You can read up on optional binding here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html  I can give a more complete example if you include `ListDataArray` and `DataArray`

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx,  I included my DataArray below:

Comment: Please edit your original post -- adding code in comments does not tend to work well

Comment: you already asked this question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082496/nested-if-statement-in-foreach-loop.

Comment: Please don't add pictures of code -- they can't be copied and pasted. Include the actual code so that someone can paste it into Xcode and try to help with your issue.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how to do it. I am stuct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested If Statement in ForEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082496/nested-if-statement-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: No, I look into all possible approaches. it doesn't work anyway. Maybe I am too stupid. Please excuse me that it has been a month that I start coding and using swiftui.

Comment: The only possible way to shorten the if statement is by using the nested ForEach loop as my second approach. But using nested ForEach crash my LazyVStack and I cannot update system images ("1.circle.fill"). Upon my understanding, the variable that I give for system images don't know how to check there are name existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution, using my solution mentioned in the comments, using `if let = ...` to do optional binding (read more on that concept here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html):

```
struct Home: View {
    
    var datas: [DataArray] = ListDataArray.dot
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach (datas, id: \.id) { data in
                    if let name1 = data.name1 {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                            Text(name1)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if let name2 = data.name2 {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)

                            Text(name2)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if let name3 = data.name3 {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "3.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)

                            Text(name3)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if let name4 = data.name4 {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "4.circle.fill")
                                                .font(.title2)
                                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                            Text(name4)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a further refactored version that splits the inner view into a separate function so that the code isn't repeated:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    var datas: [DataArray] = ListDataArray.dot
    
    @ViewBuilder func segment(imageName: String, text: String) -> some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: imageName)
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text(text)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach (datas, id: \.id) { data in
                    if let name1 = data.name1 {
                        segment(imageName: "1.circle.fill", text: name1)
                    }
                    if let name2 = data.name2 {
                        segment(imageName: "2.circle.fill", text: name2)
                    }
                    if let name3 = data.name3 {
                        segment(imageName: "3.circle.fill", text: name3)
                    }
                    if let name4 = data.name4 {
                        segment(imageName: "4.circle.fill", text: name4)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've found that when parsing SwiftUI, the compiler has trouble evaluating what would seem like simple boolean expressions. In other words, your original code *should* actually work, but the compiler has trouble parsing it.

Comment: Thank you so much @jnpdx. I can finally breathe. Also, thank you for explaining what to be aware of.

Comment: Already done!! This is a priceless answer for me. Again thank you. Never thought if let can be used in such condition.

Comment: yes you can, we told before, right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082496/nested-if-statement-in-foreach-loop